# MongoDB query to search and select the matched elements in a string array field

Tags: mongodb

Hi guys I would like to use mongodb to query songs from my music database.

Here is a sample :

```
{'date': '2018-04-27',
  'name': 'Song 1'
  'lyrics': ['',
   '',
   '[intro]',
   'lorem ipsum dolor',
   '...'
   ],
  },
 {'date': '2018-11-30',
  'name': 'Song 2'
  'lyrics': ['',
   '',
   '[intro]',
   'hello world',
   '...'
   ]
  },
 {'date': '2018-11-30',
  'name': 'Song 3'
  'lyrics': ['',
   '',
   '[intro]',
   'lorem world',
   '...'
   ]
  }
```

I would like to find songs given a regex, and retrieve the right line of lyrics where it matched

If I search for the regex "(intro|lorem)" , is it possile to get something like this ?

```
{'date': '2018-04-27',
  'name': 'Song 1'
  'lyrics': ['[intro]',
   'lorem ipsum dolor'
   ],
  },
 {'date': '2018-11-30',
  'name': 'Song 3'
  'lyrics': ['[intro]',
   'lorem world'
   ]
  }
```

Thanks a lot and take care

Answer (score 0):

Use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cnq7zLJWfGh

```
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    { lyrics: { $regex: "intro" } },
    { lyrics: { $regex: "lorem" } }
  ]
})
```